# How to draw a series of paths in a TikZ chronology diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am a beginner in LaTeX, trying to use it (and now to promote its use...) for industrial documents. I want to provide diagram relating the chronology of introducing LaTeX in an engineering group.
I had tried the [`chronology`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chronology) package, but could not change the distance between ticks from year to months. 
I have tried to mimic a chronology diagram in the following code.
However i find myself unable to nicely link with the points of the x axis to the nodes describing the steps. I have tentatively added stars (with the idea to make them invisible afterwards) in an attempt to locate where vertical lines drawn from the x axis would be angled to meet the nodes, but could not make this work. Any help appreciated as well as tips on how to improve the diagram.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\small \sf 
\tikzset{label/.style={draw=gray, ultra thin, rounded corners=.25ex, fill=gray!20,text width=4cm, text badly centered,  inner sep=.5ex, above = 2em, anchor=west,rotate=45}}
\tikzset{tick/.style={below=3pt}}
\tikzset{thinline/.style={ultra thin}}
\draw (0,0) -- (10,0);
%draw arrow 
\draw (0,0)[->, -latex] -- (13,0);
%draw 
\draw (0,0)[->, -latex] -- (13,0);
%draw vertical lines
\foreach \x in {1.2,2.2,4.2,5.2,6.2,8.2,9.2,10.2} 
               \draw (\x cm,2ex) node (\x) {*};
%draw nodes
\draw (0,0) node(A0) [tick] {0} node(B0)[] {};
\draw (1.2,0) node(A1) [tick] {1} node(B1) [label]  {end of initial investigations};
\draw (2.2,0) node (A2) [tick] {2} node(B2) [label]  {start of \LaTeX{} spare time investigations};
\draw (3.2,0) node[tick] { 3} node [] {};
\draw (4.2,0) node[tick]  {4} node[label]  {installation of \LaTeX{} on one office computer};
\draw (5.2,0) node[tick] {5} node [label] {second \LaTeX{} user};
\draw (6.2,0) node[tick] {6} node [label] {first \LaTeX{} document moved to remote server};
\draw (7.2,0) node[tick] {7} node []  {};
\draw (8.2,0) node[tick]{8} node [label]  {third \LaTeX{} user};
\draw (9.2,0) node[tick]{9} node [label]  {several documents moved on remote server};
\draw (10.2,0) node[tick] {10} node [label] {fourth \LaTeX{} user};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{chronology of events (time in months)}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\small \sf 
\tikzset{label/.style={draw=gray, ultra thin, rounded corners=.25ex, fill=gray!20,text width=4cm, text badly centered,  inner sep=.5ex, above = 2em, anchor=west,rotate=45}}
\tikzset{tick/.style={below=3pt}}
\tikzset{thinline/.style={ultra thin}}
\draw (0,0) -- (10,0);
%draw arrow 
\draw (0,0)[->, -latex] -- (13,0);
%draw 
\draw (0,0)[->, -latex] -- (13,0);
%draw vertical lines
%\foreach \x in {1.2,2.2,4.2,5.2,6.2,8.2,9.2,10.2} 
%               \draw (\x cm,2ex) node (\x) {*};
%draw nodes
\draw (0,0) node (A0) [tick] {0} node (B0)[] {};
\draw (1.2,0) node(A1) [tick] {1} node (B1) [label]  {end of initial investigations};
\draw (2.2,0) node (A2) [tick] {2} node (B2) [label]  {start of \LaTeX{} spare time investigations};
\draw (3.2,0) node[tick] (A3) {3} node (B3) [] {};
\draw (4.2,0) node[tick] (A4) {4} node (B4) [label]  {installation of \LaTeX{} on one office computer};
\draw (5.2,0) node[tick] (A5) {5} node (B5) [label] {second \LaTeX{} user};
\draw (6.2,0) node[tick] (A6) {6} node (B6) [label] {first \LaTeX{} document moved to remote server};
\draw (7.2,0) node[tick] (A7) {7} node (B7) []  {};
\draw (8.2,0) node[tick] (A8) {8} node (B8) [label]  {third \LaTeX{} user};
\draw (9.2,0) node[tick] (A9) {9} node (B9) [label]  {several documents moved on remote server};
\draw (10.2,0) node[tick] (A10) {10} node (B10)[label] {fourth \LaTeX{} user};

\foreach \nn in {1,2,4,5,6,8,9,10}
{   \draw[blue] (B\nn.west) -- ++(0,-0.75);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{chronology of events (time in months)}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You started naming your nodes (e.g A0, B1...), I just named all of them and used a `foreach` loop to draw a line stzarting from their west anchor 0.75 units down.

[image]

Comment: Yes I had started to name them, hoping this would help, but could not complete the task.