# License in LaTeX document, packages and answers

Tags: licensing

A serie of questions related themselves.

Context: I'm writting a LaTeX document and I want to license it under a GPL v3 license. I have a own package with some macros, the great majority insignificants, but any of them can be useful to other users. One of these macros is a modified version of an answer: [How to draw a series of paths in a TikZ chronology diagram?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57296/how-to-draw-a-series-of-paths-in-a-tikz-chronology-diagram/57300#57300)

- The official and third-parties LaTeX packages are licensed under LPPL. I guess my included packages are all LPPL licensed (I haven't search one by one its licenses) But, LPPL isn't compatible with GPL license. Can I use LaTeX packages in a GPL .tex document?, and why if are both mutually incompatibles?
- Is a creative commons license GPL-compatible?
- Can I use an (modify) answer (creative commons license) in a GPL document? Specially if a user specifies nothing in its user page about the license of his answers: [Relicensing code from answers](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/relicensing-code-from-answers)

I hope not to forget any important answer related to my situation.

Comment: Martin Schröder [mentioned some potential issues with the GPL in the context of LaTeX packages here a while ago](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69007/the-gpl-and-latex-packages). However, both that question and this one are 'legal', and so are location-dependent and (I think) off-topic as the need legal rather than TeX expertise. I think it might also be useful to clarify 'compatible' here: you can certainly use material with different licenses together, so the exact detail is going to be important.

Comment: What do you mean with "localtion-dependent"?

Comment: It's better to move this question to meta.tex.stackexchange.com ? Although here more users participate.

Comment: The GPL licence having tougher requirements than either the LPPL or the Creative Commons licence, I think your question should perhaps be asked to GPL people.

Comment: @Peregring-lk My point is that the legal interpretation of a license or licenses depends on the jurisdiction, and so where you are in the world. You cannot assume that each court will read the same license in the same way. In general, legal questions tend to be 'off-topic' for the entire StackExchange network as they can only be answered by someone with the appropriate expertise, and for good reason they only offer this on a paid-for basis.

Comment: I understand. I search for other sources to solve my question. Thank you very much.